# is There a Way to Give Every Anchor link inside the Navigation Menu a font size in one line?

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors, navigationbar

**"Every anchor link inside the navigation menu should have a font size of 1.5 rem. (Hint: Two elements!)"**

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Chat</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

would this work?

```
nav ul{font-size:1.5rem;}
```

Comment: does the code you have not work? What is the problem? The solution that seems to better fit your request though would be: `nav a { font-size: 1.5rem; }`

Comment: my question is can i combine 2 elements like nav and ul in one line.

Comment: you mean like: `nav a, ul a { font-size: 1.5rem; }`?

Comment: no i believe your first answer was correct: ```nav a { font-size: 1.5rem;}```

Answer (score 0):

This way only makes sense if the `<ul>` element is a direct child of the nav. Which in your case, works just fine.

```
nav > ul {
   font-size:1.5rem;
}
```

If the `<ul>` was not a direct child to your `<nav>` then I would apply a class like so:

```css
.font-size {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul class="font-size">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Chat</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```